# How to increase video illumination or brightness?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, brightness

By this I do not mean `style.filter`, I mean like in an actual video player where the user swipes up / down to increase the brightness of the video. I have made research and most of what I've found are just to increase with `style.filter`.

Comment: 1) Can you add more explanation/clarity about why you don't want an answer that uses `style.filter`? Is it because `style.filter` also affects the brightness of browser-provided video controls (the `controls` HTML attribute)? Is it important to you to support such video controls and keep them normal (no brightness changes)? 2) what you mean by "swipe up/down"? Can you give a more concrete description of this?

Comment: if you are using an actual video player maybe VLC, the effect of you increasing the video's brightness is totally different from the effect that the style.filter provides, but if perhaps you can provide an answer or idea that uses the style.filter I would appreciate.